# How do you add two methods to a slick function?

Tags: jquery, slick.js

I've got the below code:

```
$('.tab__slider' + '.' + type).slick('slickGoTo', brandIndex)

$('.tab__slider' + '.' + type)
    .addClass('active')
    .slick('getSlick')
    .refresh()
```

I want to do something like this:

```
$('.tab__slider' + '.' + type).slick({
  getSlick: '',
  'slickGoTo': brandIndex
}).refresh()
```

To shorten my code.

Yeah it works how it is but there must be a way to concatenate the two methods to create tidier code but I can't find where I'd do this in the docs so coming here.

Answer (score 0):

From the [options and methods available in their documentation](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/#settings), it looks like the pattern they follow is to have each call separated out with its own argument(s). There are no cases where you can send multiple properties in an object. In other words, it looks like what you're trying to do isn't possible in the manner you're attempting.

That said, you can make the code a little more succinct by saving the jQuery object you create, like this:

```
var $slider = $('.tab__slider' + '.' + type).addClass('active');
$slider.slick('slickGoTo', brandIndex);
$slider.slick('getSlick').refresh();
```

Comment: hmm yeah true I could clean this up like the above example. Just feels like you should be able to do it

Comment: It all depends on how the plugin is architected as it's not a standard JS feature. In this instance the author has followed a different pattern. Although, it does seem a little odd that you'd want to set the active slide and then immediately refresh it.

Comment: yeah tbh I found that strange.. If I do it the other way round it doesn't keep its index and just loads it on the first slide